# What is the effect of plant food on all types of plants?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

A new feature in the new plants vs zombies game is *plant food* that you can feed to your plants for a (temporary?) power boost.

For example, feeding your sunflowers makes them produce like 5 suns on a row, feeding your cannon flowers makes them have a burst of fire.

What are the effects on the other types of plants?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a table from [Plant Food](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Plant_Food):

> **Peashooter**: Turns them into faster-shooting Gatling Peas for three seconds. They shoot approximately 20 peas a second.
>   **Sunflower**: Produces 150 sun.
>   **Wall-nut**: Gives it a hard armor shell for extra strength.
>   **Potato Mine**: Arms itself and produces two armed Potato Mines on other spaces.
>   **Cabbage-pult**: Launches several cabbages at once, hitting every zombie and grave onscreen.
>   **Bloomerang**: Shoots approximately ten boomerangs in four directions, up, down, left and right.
>   **Iceberg Lettuce**: Freezes every zombie on screen, similar to the Ice-shroom.
>   **Twin Sunflower**: Gives 250 sun.
>   **Bonk Choy**: Punches zombies in every direction at a very fast rate.
>   **Repeater**: Shoots like a Gatling Pea at first, but at the end it shoots a 2x bigger Pea.
>   **Kernel-pult**: Launches several butter at once, hitting every zombie and grave onscreen.
>   **Snapdragon**: Sets a 3x3 area in front of it on fire killing all zombies on those spaces.
>   **Spikeweed**: Temporarily fills the row with other spikes poking up from the ground and pulls zombie to the Spikeweed.
>   **Coconut Cannon**: Fires one big Coconut that kills all zombies in a row.
>   **Spring Bean**: Bounces all zombies on screen.
>   **Spikerock**: Temporarily fills the row with other spikes poking up from the ground and pulls zombies to the Spikerock.
>   **Threepeater**: Shoots a wildfire of peas across the area.
>   **Split Pea**: Both heads shoot peas like fast-shooting Gatling Peas. The Repeater head fires a big pea at the end.
>   **Chili Bean**: Launches 3 extra beans randomly.
>   **Lightning Reed**: Makes a storm cloud that damages the zombies with lightning.
>   **Tall-nut**: Gives it a hard armor for extra strength like Wall-nut.
>   **Pea Pod**: Gains a giant Peashooter head that shoots five big peas which do a lot of damage.
>   **Melon-pult**: Launches melons out from the top that does 2x the damage to all zombies.
>   **Winter Melon**: Same as Melon-pult with added slowing effect.
>   **Imitater**: As the Imitated Plant
>   **Snow Pea**: It shoots a lot of frozen peas
>   **Torchwood**: The fire becomes napalm.

For full information there is the website above.

Comment: The Sunflower actually produces 150 sun, and the twin sunflower produces 225 sun.

Comment: If you are going to edit your post, make sure to fix the errors in it at least...

Answer (score 4):

Laser Bean - Shoots a giant laser killing all zombies in a lane.

Blover - N/A

Citron - Shoots an electric ball throwing away all zombies on it's lane. Will stop at any robot or Gargantuar.

E.M. Peach - N/A

Star Fruit - Spins around shooting giant stars in 5 directions.

Infi-nut - Makes a forcefield on the whole column in front of it.

Magnifying Grass - Shoots a powerful rainbow killing most of the zombies in front of it. Lasts longer if a sun producing plant is nearby.

Tile Turnip - N/A

Hypno-shroom - Turns the first zombie to eat it into a hypnotised Gargantuar.

Sun-shroom - Grows to full size and produces 225 sun.

Puff-shroom - All Puff-shrooms on screen will shoot 30 spores, increasing their time before they die.

Fume-shroom - Shoots a giant fume which push back all zombies in the lane.

Sun Bean - Makes the first zombie to eat it explode and give 15 sun for each NDS left.

Pea-nut - Shoots 60 peas and has a helmet for extra health.

Magnet-shroom - Pulls in all metal items and bounces them back.

Chomper - Sucks in all zombies on it's lane into its mouth then burps, pushing the leftover zombies back.

Lily Pad - Makes an add shape of Lily Pads around it.

Tangle Kelp - Pulls down 4 zombies in the water

Bowling Bulb - Shoots 3 electric bulbs when a zombie walks on the lane.

Ghost Pepper (Limited time only) - Haunts all zombies in a 3X4 area.

```
              More for Big Wave Beach Part 2 coming soon
```